# VB.net loop through records in particular order

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have a datatable and it is filled with data in particular order. Once the data is in the table I need to perform some calculations on additional fields, but I need to do that from the bottom row if that makes sense?

At the moment I came up with the below:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In Me.DataSet1.MyDataTable()

        Dim parent_warehouse As String = dr("WH")
        Dim parent_product As String = dr("ProductCode")
        Dim new_material = 0
        Dim new_labour = 0
        Dim new_overhead = 0
        Dim new_outwork = 0
        Dim new_total = 0

        If isassembly(parent_warehouse, parent_product) Then
            If Not IsDBNull(dr("assy")) Then

                For Each dr1 As DataRow In Me.DataSet1.MyDataTable()
                    Dim assy = dr("assy")
                    If assy = parent_warehouse + parent_product Then
                        new_material = new_material + (dr1("material") * (dr1("UsageQuantity") / dr1("Wastage")))
                        new_labour = new_labour + (dr1("labour") * dr1("UsageQuantity"))
                        new_overhead = new_overhead + (dr1("overhead") * dr1("UsageQuantity"))
                        new_outwork = new_outwork + (dr1("outwork") * dr1("UsageQuantity"))
                        new_total = new_material + new_labour + new_overhead + new_outwork
                    End If
                Next
                dr("new_material") = new_material
                dr("new_labour") = new_labour
                dr("new_overhead") = new_overhead
                dr("new_outwork") = new_outwork
                dr("new_total") = new_total
            Else
                GoTo skip
            End If
        Else
            dr("new_material") = dr("material")
            dr("new_labour") = dr("labour")
            dr("new_overhead") = dr("overhead")
            dr("new_outwork") = dr("outwork")
            dr("new_total") = dr("total")
        End If
skip:
    Next
```

The issue I have with this currently is that when it loops through the records it goes through them Top to bottom where I want it to loop bottom to top as the costs are supposed to be built up from the bottom products up so that their parent product gets a new cost and do that all the way up to the top item.

Comment: Don't use a For-Each.  Use a For-Loop in reverse.

Comment: I'd turn this into a variable ````Me.DataSet1.MyDataTable()```` like a DataTable or DataRowCollection, and then loop backwards.  ````Dim dt As DataTable =  Me.DataSet1.MyDataTable()```` and then ````For i as Integer = dt.Rows.Count - 1 to 0 Step -1````

Comment: And you also might think about handling some of these calculations in the SQL query to save time. As of right now you are looping through your results set two different times, and depending on the size of that set it could be a lot more efficient to do it in the query.

Comment: @JohnPete22 I'm pulling raw data from SQL and want to do calculations in the app itself to as we don't want to use SQL's processing power if that makes sense and have the app load a bit longer instead. Also, your first comment was a solution to my issue, the For loop has worked to loop backwards - do you want to post it as an answer instead of a comment so I can flag it as an answer? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backwards loop is going to be your best option.  You'll utilize a For Loop with a `Step -1`

```
' declare a variable for our DataTable
Dim dt As DataTable = Me.DataSet1.MyDataTable()

' we're setting our 'i' variable to the last row (account for 0-index)
' in a typical For Loop, the Step is +1, but we're specifying -1 to go backwards
For i as Integer = dt.Rows.Count - 1 to 0 Step -1
   ' execute logic
   ' something like CDec(dt.Rows(i).Item("DecimalColumn")) to convert decimal type
   ' CInt(), CStr(), CDate() are also very useful, Integer, String, and Date respectively
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to sort the default view of the table, and then loop through the default view.

```
Me.DataSet1.MyDataTable.defaultview.sort = "material", "labor" 'etc.

For Each dr As DataRowView In Me.DataSet1.MyDataTable.defaultview
'...
```

*Edited per @jmcilhinney's correction in the comments. -- Thanks!

Comment: Each item in the `DefaultView` is a `DataRowView` rather than a `DataRow`. I think the idea of using a `For` loop backwards is better in this particular case though.

Comment: Like @jmcilhinney mentioned I went with the For loop to loop backwards as I require the DataTable to have the data sorted in a different order to the order I require to run through the items in this case.